# How to upgrade Python version on Azure HDInsight

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-hdinsight

We need to use an external library which only runs on Python 3.6 or higher. Unfortunately, HDInsight only has Python 3.5 installed by default.
Is there a way to upgrade the minor version for Python on HDInsight?

The official Azure documentation does not mention about it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-python-package-installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/139199/upgrade-hdinsight-python-version.html):

> It's not recommended as using non-cluster built-in Python versions are unsupported scenario.

***WARNING!***: HDInsight cluster depends on the built-in Python environment - Python 3.5. Directly installing custom packages in those default built-in environments may cause unexpected library version changes. And break the cluster further.

> If you want to install, you can use Python 3.6, change “python=3.5” in this command to python=3.6, and follow the rest steps in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-python-package-installation) works.

```
sudo /usr/bin/anaconda/bin/conda create --prefix /usr/bin/anaconda/envs/py36new python=3.6 anaconda –yes
```